# Extract the boundary from a ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a function like this `Exp[-(\[Psi]+\[Delta]* x)^2/2]`. I need to numerically integrate this function and represent using ListContourPlot. Hence I Use the code like this

```
t2 = Flatten[
  Table[{\[Psi], \[Delta], 
    If[0 < NIntegrate[
       Exp[-(\[Psi]+\[Delta]* x)^2/2], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}] < 3, 0, 
     1]}, {\[Psi], -0.01, -2, -01}, {\[Delta], 0.1, 5, 01}], 1]

ListContourPlot[t2, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Evaluate@plotset2, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.01, -1}, {0, 4}}, PlotLegends -> None, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\[Psi]", "\[Delta]"}, Contours -> 1]
```

and I obtain the plot as:

[image]

Now, I need to extract the line that separates these two regions (blue and cream region). I know that the boundary indicates the region where the function has value not within the interval. So I think If there is a way to extract the values of psi and delta when the value of the integral changes will serve the purpose. I am not sure.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the picture  does not match the updated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The integral can be done analytically

```
int[ψ_, δ_] = Assuming[Element[{ψ, δ}, Reals],
  Integrate[Exp[-(ψ*δ*x)^2/2], {x, 0, ∞}]]

(* Sqrt[π/2]/(Abs[δ] Abs[ψ]) *)

f[ψ_, δ_] = 
 Piecewise[{{1, int[ψ, δ] <= 0 || int[ψ, δ] >= 3}}] // Simplify

(* Piecewise[
   {{1, Sqrt[2*Pi]/(Abs[δ]*Abs[ψ]) >= 6}}, 0] *)
```

The boundary is `int[ψ, δ] == 3`

```
Simplify[Solve[{int[ψ, δ] == 3, ψ < 0, δ > 
     0}, δ][[1]], ψ < 0]

(* {δ -> -(Sqrt[(π/2)]/(3 ψ))} *)

Show[
 ContourPlot[f[ψ, δ], {ψ, -0.01, -1}, {δ, 0, 4},
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
  PlotRange -> {{-0.01, -1}, {0, 4}},
  PlotLegends -> None,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"ψ", "δ"})],
 Plot[-Sqrt[Pi/2]/(3 ψ), {ψ, -0.01, -1},
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For the revised function

```
t2 = Flatten[
   Table[{ψ, δ, 
     If[0 < NIntegrate[Exp[-(ψ + δ*x)^2/2], {x, 0, ∞}] <
        3, 0, 1]}, {ψ, -0.01, -2, -0.025}, {δ, 0.01, 5, 0.025}], 
   1];
```

Select the `{ψ, δ}` pairs on the boundary

```
boundary = 
  First[MaximalBy[#, Last]] & /@ 
   GatherBy[Most /@ Select[t2, #[[3]] == 1 &], First];
```

Use [`FindFormula`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html) to find a function that fits the boundary values

```
b[ψ_] = FindFormula[boundary, ψ]

(* 0.403272 - 0.369685 ψ - 0.0845795 ψ^2 *)

Show[
 ListContourPlot[t2,
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
  PlotRange -> {{-0.01, -2}, {0, 2}},
  PlotLegends -> None,
  FrameLabel -> {"ψ", "δ"}],
 Plot[b[ψ], {ψ, -2, -0.01},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. But what if my function is not solvable analytically?? For example, Please see the edited question...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired contour using the analytical solution for `Integrate[Exp[-(ψ + δ x)^2/2], {x, 0, ∞}]` under the assumptions  `ψ` and  `δ` are real and `δ` is non-zero:

```
ClearAll[ψδcontour]
ψδcontour[ψ_, δ_] := FullSimplify[Integrate[Exp[-(ψ + δ x)^2/2], {x, 0, ∞}], 
 (ψ | δ) ∈ Reals && δ != 0]

ψδcontour[ψ, δ] // TeXForm
```

> $$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(\left| \delta \right| -\delta  \text{erf}\left(\frac{\psi }{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)}{\delta ^2}$$

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[ψδcontour[ψ, δ]], {ψ, -2, 0}, {δ, 0, 3}, 
 Contours -> {3}, 
 ContourLabels -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
 ContourShading -> {LightBlue, Yellow}, 
 BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 16, 
 FrameLabel -> {ψ, δ}]
```

[image]

Plotting multiple contours:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[ψδcontour[ψ, δ]], {ψ, -2, 0}, {δ, 0, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> All,  
 Contours -> Range[4], 
 ContourLabels -> True, 
 ContourShading -> None, 
 ContourStyle -> (Directive[Thick, #] & /@ { Red, Green, Blue, Orange}), 
 BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 16,
 FrameLabel -> {ψ, δ}]
```

[image]

***"what if my function is not solvable analytically?"***

You can extract the contour line coordinates from `ListContourPlot` output (using `Cases`) to construct a [`BSplineFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineFunction.html) and use it with `ParametricPlot`:

Using Bob Hanlon's setup to get `t2`:

```
t2 = Flatten[Table[{ψ, δ, 
   If[0 < NIntegrate[Exp[-(ψ + δ*x)^2/2], {x, 0, ∞}] < 3, 0, 1]},
    {ψ, -0.01, -2, -0.025}, {δ, 0.01, 5, 0.025}],  1];

lcp = ListContourPlot[t2, FrameLabel -> {"ψ", "δ"}, 
   PlotRange -> All, BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 16, 
   FrameLabel -> {ψ, δ}, ImageSize -> Medium];

bSF = Cases[Normal[lcp], Line[x_] :> BSplineFunction[x], All][[1]];

Row[{lcp, Show[lcp, ParametricPlot[bSF[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]]]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]